# How to find the directory of the .app that a python script is running from

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, py2app

I recently made a python script that goes through files in whatever directory it is placed in and renames them based on certain criteria. The script works perfectly, and I compiled the script into an OS X .app using py2app. This worked fine as well. However now when I run the script, it searches through the files in the ".app/contents/macOS" folder (where the script is located) rather than where the ".app" is actually located.

This is because it has this code at the start:

```
src = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

which assigns the the location of the ".py" file to a variable which is then used extensively throughout the script. Is there any way I can instead add a snippet of code which tells python the path location of the ".app" that the ".py" file is executing from?

If not, perhaps there is a way to get a file explorer window open, from there it would be possible for a user to select a folder who's path would then get assigned to the "src" variable. I'm very new to python however so this would certainly be a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

From docs:

> **getcwd()**
>
> Return a unicode string representing the current working directory.

Comment: @thanks for the reply much appreciated, unfortunately that doesn't work and the same problem arises, I think I'm gonna have to use tkinter to prompt the user to pick a directory. Will add the code when I'm done

Comment: @Ruthus99 sure.

Answer (score 0):

To find the location of the `.app` directory that wraps the application, the most direct way is to modify the path that you find with your current code. After computing `src` as you did, just trim it like this and use `app` as the path:

```
import re
...
app, rest = re.split(r"/[^/]*\.app/", src, 1)
```

This stops at the first path component that ends in `.app`. If you prefer you can hard-code your application name, e.g. `/myprogram.app/`.

PS. I'm puzzled as to why you copy your app to the folder you want to modify. A file selection dialog, or drag and drop, is the more common (and easier) way to tell a program what to work on. OS X applications created with `py2app` support drag and drop: Your program can get the path to the dropped directory like this:

```
import sys
folders = sys.argv[1:]   # Handles multiple arguments
for folder in folders:
    do_something_in(folder)
```

Then simply drag and drop the directory or directories you want to process onto the application icon, which you can just keep on your desktop, the Finder's sidebar, or a favorite directory -- no need to copy it each time you use it, and no need for it to know where its source is.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a module to accomplish this task.

https://pypi.org/project/macos-application-location/

Basically, a `.app` is just a directory of an application package. The location of `.app` will be a few parent directories of where the actual binary is.

Usage:

```py
import pathlib

import macos_application_location


app_path: pathlib.Path = macos_application_location.get()
```

In addition, we must ensure that the gatekeeper path randomization, also known as app translocation, does not cause any disruptions. Reference: [App Translocation Notes](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/724969).

Comment: the code seems sort enough that you can at least also give a brief description of how the package works and how to use it in this answer post. see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/997587